# Polynomial function from $S^3$ to $S^3$ and quaternions

Tags: quaternions, algebraic-groups

I am searching the polynomial functions from $S^3$ to $S^3$.

($S^3$ is the set of vectors $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\|x\|=1$)

We say $g$ is a polynomial function from $S^3$ to $S^3$, if there exists $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4 \in \mathbb{R}[X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4]$ and
 $f:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$, $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \mapsto (f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4),...,f_4(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4))$ such that $g: S^3 \rightarrow S^3$, maps $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ to $ f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$

We generate the set $F$ of functions from $S^3$ to $S^3$ by:

- the constant functions belong to $F$,
- the identity belongs to $F$,
- the isometries belong to $F$,
- if $f,g \in F$,  $\overline{f} \in F$, and $f \circ g\in F$, and $ f \times g\in F$, where $\overline{z}$ is the conjuguate of $z$ in the quaternions, and $\times$ is the quaternions product.

Do all the polynomial functions from $S^3$ to $S^3$ belong to $F$ ?

We have identified $S^3$ with the set of quaternions $z$ such that $|z|=1$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to add the isometries separately to $F$.  Every isometry of $S^3$ is of the form $g(z) = pzq$ for $p,q\in S^3$ (if it is orientation preseriving) or $g(z) = p{\bar z}q$ for $p,q\in S^3$ (if it is not orientation preserving), so they are already made from your other allowable constructions, since you have added the identity and the constant functions and have closed it under composition and multiplication.

Comment: So, $F$ is the set of functions that can be written $\Pi_i p_i z^{n_i} q_i \overline{z_i}^{m_i}$

Comment: The question can be reformulated in such a way that it applies to any algebraic group $G$ over $k$: Let $G(X)$ be the group of all morphisms $X\to G$ of varieties over $k$. The question is, is $G(G)$ generated by $G(k)$ together with the single element $1:G\to G$?  (This latter element is the identity, but in this context that is a problematic name for it!)

I don't know the answer when $k=\mathbb R$ and $G$ is the quaternion group $S^3$. A related case would be $k=\mathbb C$ and $G=SL_2$. 


Comment: Thanks. In the reformulation, how $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is generated ?

Comment: $\overline z=z^{-1}$.

Comment: @Tom, I think for general algebraic group this is unlikely to be true -- if the group has "interesting" outer automorphisms (or even endoorphisms) then it seems unlikely that you can obtain $g \to \sigma(z)$ from your generators.
The first case, I can think of, where this problem occurs is when $G=SL_3$ and $\sigma(g) = (g^T)^{-1}$. Also in positive characteristic one might use maps build form the Frobenious endomorphism.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to suggest that it is true in many cases. It is false for the additive group.

Comment: @Tom, I think with suitable modification this might be true for simple alebraic groups

Comment: Let $(1,i,j,k)$ a $\mathbb{R}$-basis of the quaternions, with $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$, and $ij=-ji=k$. If $f(x+iy+jz+kt)=(x^2+y^2)+i(z^2+t^2)+\sqrt{2}(x+iy)(z+it)j$, $f$ is polynomial but it seems not to belong to $F$, because $f$ is of degree $2$. If $f \in F$, $f=pzqzr$ or $f=p\overline{z}qzr$ or $f=pzq\overline{z}r$ or $f=p\overline{z}q\overline{z}r$.